# Child window load event not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular

When opening a blank child window by using `window.open('', 'name')` its **load** event is not working in Firefox. While in chrome it does work.

see my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-window-load?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  - in chrome you can see the console log message, but in Firefox you don't.

Also the `readyState` in Firefox is not working as expected and not updated.

What am I missing? how to solve this?

Comment: Might be pop up block in firefox... check the setting

Comment: @souravsatyam nope, no blocking, the child window is opened, see demo.

Comment: For me the code is opening the window in chrome and mozilla both

Comment: @souravsatyam plz read my question again, the issue is "load event is not working in firefox"

Comment: Hey in your window.open actual code not this example code are you trying to open a page in the same domain as your app or a external domain?@shemesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value), `window.open` returns `WindowProxy` instance, which proxies all the properties that `Window` object contains, including `onload` and `addEventListener`. The main goal of proxying is to restrict the newly created `window` from unauthorized access from the parent `window`. The access is controlled by the browser that allows the parent `window` to interact with the child instance only if the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is met by both these tabs. Without this security rule, anyone can modify or programmatically read some info that `window` of any other site contains directly from their code.

On my machine, your stackblitz repro doesn't work as you expect even in Chrome. Opening a new `Window` with the same origin fixes the problem in both Chrome or Firefox:

```
window.open('https://angular-child-window-load.stackblitz.io', 'kush', 'width=222, height=222, top=222, left=222');
```

I think you may have some same-origin policies modified in your Chrome configuration, or maybe there is another local problem.

Comment: i'm trying to build a generic component that opens a blank(!) child window then push some stuff into it. meaning the child window does not have a URL. does that mean i cannot hook to the load event?

Comment: @shemesh This means you have no ability to access a child window from the parent one in your case. The parent window has some origin, and the child window doesn't have the same origin, because absence of origin is handled as different origin. So you cannot hook into any event of the child, and almost all the data of the child window cannot even be read from the parent. What I think you can do is to have some page in your site with dynamic content and open a new tab with that page, passing the content into it from the parent page.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in the arrow function.

`win.onload = () = > { }`  makes a reference out of `window.onload` to an anonoymous function. The function doesn't run. It's equal to `win.onload = function() {}` which won't run either.

What will work is creating a **new** function

```
win.onload = new function() {
    console.log('--- new window loaded ---')
}
```

Comment: but this is not hooking to the onload event